# Is an abstract-syntax-tree always a binary tree?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I have seen many examples of AST doing `arithmetic operations` which look like this:

```
   +
 /   \
1     2
```

above represent `1 + 2`. My question is, are all ASTs binary by definition or a node could possibly have more than 2 children?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in an AST, nodes often have more than two children. For example, a block of code is typically a node with an array of child nodes, which are statements.